AC circuit board still blinking after disconnect - safe to remove capacitor?
My HVAC unit stopped running, and the tech said it was a blown transformer. I replaced the transformer and the blower unit started working. However, the AC unit will not start. I have tried disconnecting the power of the disconnect box and reconnecting it, but no luck.
I want to see if the problem is a blown capacitor. I removed the panel and saw that the circuit board light is blinking green even though I pulled out the disconnect. Is it safe to remove the capacitor?
Or can I test it while it’s still connected?
